# The change-of-monoid adjunction between categories of modules induced by a morphism of monoids

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, modules, adjoint-functors, symmetric-monoidal-categories

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a cocomplete closed symmetric monoidal category. Let $A, B$ be monoids in $\mathcal{M}$ and $f: A \rightarrow B$ be a morphism of monoids. The morphism $f$ induces the extension of scalars functor and the restriction of scalars functor between the categories ${_A\mathrm{Mod}}$ of left $A$-modules and ${_B\mathrm{Mod}}$ of left $B$-modules. These functors form an adjunction between these categories. I am looking for a reference for this adjunction.

In other words, I am looking for a reference to [the change of rings adjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_rings#Relation_between_the_extension_of_scalars_and_the_restriction_of_scalars) but in the more general case of monoids in a cocomplete closed symmetric monoidal category.

Comment: The *enriched* category theory literature should have this somewhere. Monoids in $\newcommand{\M}{\mathcal{M}}\M$ are one-object $\M$-categories, and modules correspond to $\M$-enriched presheaves, so the change-of-monoid adjunction is a special case of change-of-base between enriched presheaf categories $[A,\M] \to [B,\M]$.  Surprisingly, checking a couple of standard sources (Dubuc, Kelly) I can’t find a clean reference for this adjunction either!  But searching on keywords “enriched presheaves”, “enriched Kan extensions”, “enriched realization” may be helpful.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine This appears in [Enriched Model Categories and Presheaf Categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.3567) as Lemma 2.2.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Thanks a lot! I was not aware of this perspective! That was really helpful!

Comment: @ConnorMalin That's the adjunction I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly overkill, but this result is a special case of `change of operads' since the given morphism of monoids induces a morphism from the operad $O$ for left $A$-modules to the operad $P$ for left $B$-modules. A published reference is Corollary 5.1.1 in [Homotopical Adjoint Lifting Theorem](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10485-019-09560-2). Tracing through the proof and ignoring all the stuff about model categories, the key categorical result we rely on there is the [Adjoint Lifting Theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+lifting+theorem), for which we reference [Borceux's](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/handbook-of-categorical-algebra/EF86DCA2B6B7BBA10CE255ABC572601B) volume 2, Theorem 4.5.6 on page 226. When we use this result, we take (using the notation of diagram 3.3.6 in our paper) $L = R = Id$ on the underlying category, and so $f^*$ is given by restriction along $f$. In case you don't want to rely on Borceux for the left adjoint, $f_!$ you can also get a direct construction from Section 4 of [Resolution of coloured operads and rectification of homotopy algebras](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0512576.pdf) paper by Berger and Moerdijk, which again works in the generality of operads.